# Is a thread guaranteed for the entire request handled by a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, exception

I am running into a situation where I use ThreadLocal static variable to hold a bean that contains various metrics values from different classes during the lifecycle of the request. In a filter I create the bean and set it in a thread local variable and remove it from the thread local variable in the same filter after request has been processed. What I am running into is that the bean containing values from other requests! The only explanation for this is the thread being shared to process multiple requests at the same time. So the question in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While one thread will generally process a single request (speaking about tomcat, for sure), the thread may process multiple requests over time but not w/o finishing the existing request, unless using include/forward alikes.

I'd VERY strognly recommend you to use attribute (setAttribute()) of the said request w/ your bean and use it for profiling. If you can't provide the request to various methods... well you are stuck w/ the ThreadLocal [which is not so bad solution].

Alternatively you can post the code how you install/remove the threadLocal bean.

Keep in mind that you have to to some managing the of that bean as well (it will not be available outside the request).

Edit: forgot to ask: do you use try/finally calling doFilter(...)?

the code should be like that

```
installBean();
try{
  chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}finally{
 Bean b = deinstallBean();
 useTheMetrics(b);
//potentially, process exception, etc
}
```

Comment: Yes the "finally" did the magic. Like Michael and erickson were saying, in one case a runtime exception didn't remove the bean. Thank you.

Comment: Rule of the thumb (or moral of the story): If you modify ANY global state and intend to reverse it back. Use try/finally, actually use try/finally any clean-up/close/dispose (or implicit rollback) is needed, it's almost doesn't incur any performance penalties (consider it free :D )

Answer (score 2):

It could also be that your filter is not always called in the sequence you expect it to be. Threads are reused to process multiple requests one after another, so if the removal of the value in the `ThreadLocal` does not happen, it will still be there when the thread processes its next request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assume that a single thread will process each request.

Use a `finally` block to clear (set to `null`) the `ThreadLocal` in the filter after processing the rest of the chain. That will prevent data from previous requests from being mingled with the current request.

Comment: why is it safe to assume that? is there a standard that says a single thread will process all filters for a servlet and the servlet itself? wasn't there something about a clustered app server so a bunch of JVMs together act as an app server?